# Zookeeper: how not to lose a watch?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

> Watches are one time triggers; if you get a watch event and you want
>   to get notified of future changes, you must set another watch.

Lets assume, there is a znode which's data is updated every 5-100 sec. I want to maintain a local copy of it's data. So my algorithm is:

1. call `get(znode, set_watch=true)` to set a watch
2. [on znode's data changed:](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/zookeeper/ZooKeeperListener.html#nodeDataChanged(java.lang.String))

   1. a step with potential programmer's mistake
   2. `local_copy = get(znode, set_watch=true)` to get local copy and set another watch

So a single exception on step 2.1 makes step 2.2 be skipped which means another watch is not set and all future updates will be lost.

What is the general way to write **robust** data-changed listener? My current dirty workaround is to set additional watches by timer.

Comment: Why not wrap 2.1 in try/catch scope, or better yet if try/finally - where 2.2 will happen in finally?

Comment: Why not  use Apache curator framework? look at TreeCache ,it maintains local copy of all the znodes.